# Image not centered on website, centered on mobile device

Tags: image, formatting, size, center

I'm working on something for a competition, and the code must be available on mobile. I have the code in right now, but the image is not centered on the website. On a mobile device, the image is centered.
If we try to center the image on the website, the image will cut off on a mobile device.

---

```
<div style = "margin-left: 12.5%; display: block;">
    <img src = "images/Files for contact page/FINAL.png" alt="" usemap="#map" />
    <map name = "map">
        <area shape = "circle" coords="682, 392, 70" href = "https://apprentices-flynboy.c9users.io/forum" />
        <area shape = "circle" coords="338, 389, 70" href = "https://apprentices-flynboy.c9users.io/forum" />
        <area shape = "circle" coords="831, 164, 70" href = "https://apprentices-flynboy.c9users.io/forum" />
        <area shape = "circle" coords="510, 163, 70" href = "https://apprentices-flynboy.c9users.io/forum" />
        <area shape = "circle" coords="199, 173, 70" href = "https://apprentices-flynboy.c9users.io/forum" />
    </map>
  </div>
```

---

I'm sorry for my horrible formatting. I've never used this site before, so I'm trying to learn!

Answer (score 0):

I admit this is a horrible answer since I think center is deprecated.

But I feel I run into these issues all the time and the one thing that consistantly works is `<center>`.  You might also try moving your image outside of your block.

```
<center>
img
</center>
```

It's been years since i've done html daily but its worth a try.